# My dataframe keeps making columns with name 'Unnamed'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\bossd\OneDrive\Документы\datarn.csv")
df.drop(columns = df.columns[0], axis = 1)
display(df)
```

Everytime i want to delete the first column which always gets named 'Unnamed' and appears everytime i want to save changes with

```
df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\bossd\OneDrive\Документы\datarn.csv")
```

And after i do this the column reappers or just doesn't delete, how do i delete these unnamed rows and save changes to a dataframe to be completely clear from these columns and have 'timestamp' as first column.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q66ha.png)

Tried doing

```
df = df.drop(columns = df.columns[0], axis = 1)
```

but it doesn't help me with this problem and the columns keep appearing

Also whenever i open the csv file i get this additional column that didn't exist before

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ9WN.png)

Comment: "Everytime i want to delete the first row" do you mean the first column?

Comment: Yeah, column, fixed

Comment: You shouldn't specify both columns= and axis=1. It's one or the other. Try this.  df = df.drop(columns = ["Unnamed"])

Comment: doesn't work, deleted 1 column but doesn't delete further

Comment: Are there multiple columns that start with Unnamed? What further needs deleted?

Comment: There are currently 6 of them that are named: Unnamed 0.5, Unnamed 0.4, Unnamed 0.3, Unnamed 0.2, Unnamed 0.1, Unnamed 0. I think they duplicated after i tried saving the file after deleting the first row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is when you are saving DF by default it adds an index column without a title hence the unmaned0 column appears in your DF when loading it again as this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77077917/17793531) suggest you can delete multiple column with the same name but I'd like to add that when saving the DF to CSV -or any file format-
You can add index=False to not have an index column
for example:

```py
df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\bossd\OneDrive\Документы\datarn.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: Holy sh-, thank you so much pal, you have one of the solutions to my problems, the person above fixed the unnamed columns and you fixed the first column reappearing. Thank you so much/

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

To drop multiple columns whose column name starts with 'Unnamed'

```
cols_to_drop = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('Unnamed')]

df.drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: This will take care of all of them at once.

Comment: It actually did take care, but everytime i run `df.to_csv(path) display(df)` the unnamed columns reappear

Comment: Right, as explained in the other answer, you continually regenerate the Unnamed columns based on the way you save and load your dataframes. My answer explained only how to purge them which was your question.

Comment: Sorry for not hitting your answer the correct one, can't hit multiple of them, you still helped me out greatly, appreciated!